# How to translate this code from VB.NET to C#? (translators are not working)

Tags: c#, vb.net, timespan, code-translation

I'm having problems translating this code to C# from VB.NET. This code is supposed to take a value from each cell of a column in a database (let's call it column1, it's data type is datetime, so, the format is like this: 12/19/2011 7:42:30 PM), and find the timespan between the Datetime.Now and that value of column1 for each row in a gridview control. Some guy gave me this code that works perfectly in VB.NET:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TimeSpan"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# TimeSpan(IIf(IsDBNull(Eval("column1")), DateTime.Now,Eval("column1"))) %>'></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

And for the codebehind:

```
Protected Function TimeSpan(ByVal Duration As DateTime) As TimeSpan
        Dim date1 As DateTime = Duration
        Dim date2 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = (date2 - date1)
        Return ts
    End Function
```

And in VB.NET it works, but when I try to translate it to C#, and run my application, I get these two errors:

-The best overloaded method match for '_Default.TimeSpan(System.DateTime)' has some invalid argument
-Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.DateTime'

Can someone please help me with this? A translation that works for the code? Or even another way of doing what I want to do? 
Thanks

Edited: This is the code (in C#, which I get using translators), which is actually the code that gives me the exceptions that I mentioned before:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TimeSpan"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# TimeSpan((Information.IsDBNull(Eval("column1")) ? DateTime.Now : Eval("column1")))
 %>'></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

And for the code behind:

```
protected TimeSpan TimeSpan(DateTime Duration)
{
    DateTime date1 = Duration;
    DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts = (date2 - date1);
    return ts;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the C# code that you've tried translating it to?

Comment: The parameter naming on that function seems incredibly misleading.  You are passing in the **start time** and returning the **duration**.

Comment: The naming hurts my brain. A `DateTime` called `Duration`, and a method called `TimeSpan`. The function should be called something like `Age`.

Comment: I edited with the code in c# that gives me the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with the calling code not woth the function itself.

The error says that you try to pass a value of type `object` to your function `TimeSpan`. But the only parameter of that function is of type `DateTime`.

When you show the code calling the function `TimeSpan` i can give you advice what to change.

But as others suggested, the naming of your function and the parameter is very missleading.

**EDIT**

Ok, now i see your calling code. You have to cast the value of `Eval("column1")` to DateTime:

```
<%# TimeSpan(Eval("column1") == System.DBNull.Value 
                     ? DateTime.Now
                     : (DateTime)Eval("column1")) %>
```

Comment: he has shown the call (the first code block with the tags) and he does indeed need to do some type conversion on it.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, now i have my glasses on - i have already updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that I had to cast it, now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is you call your method TimeSpan. Try calling it something else (such as ToTimeSpan).

Comment: The compiler error says something else. I think `TimeSpan` is a valid name for a function even if its misleading.

Answer (score 2):

The code translates to (with sensible rename):

```
public TimeSpan GetDuration(DateTime start)
{
   return DateTime.Now - start;
}
```

which you should just do inline, no need for a method IMO.

Comment: Really? It looks as if a human wrote the C# code, and a computer translated it to VB.NET ...

Comment: Just change the method name to avoid errors... but this is the translation.

Comment: @zmbq..sorry, I don't get you?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is probably that Eval("column1") is returning an objet and your TimeSpan method doesn't accept objects, it accepts DateTimes. Do a conversion to a DateTime and I think it may start working.

ie

```
<%# TimeSpan(IIf(IsDBNull(Eval("column1")), DateTime.Now,Ctype(Eval("column1"), DateTime))) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast your input text information to datetime :).
Otherwise, you could use your method TimeSpan ... it s stub and you right ;)